# How to select a row who have the same value in the other row in a certain field(without selecting the other row too)

Tags: mysql

Hi i'm just new to sql and i can't understand how the union works. it says that i need to retrieve all the other (not s001) students who have learned the same courses as ‘s001’ has learned using Union or intersect or minus. And i make a query and it didn't work it has error. my query is:

`select student.* from student,subjcode where subjcode.sno!='s001' union select subjcode.* from subjcode,student where subjcode.sno='s001' and subjcode.sno=student.sno;`

the table subjcode is:

```
sno     cno     score
S001    C001    78.90
S001    C002    82.90
S001    C003    59.00
S002    C001    80.90
S002    C002    72.90
S003    C001    81.90
S003    C002    81.90
S004    C001    60.90
S005    C002    50.00
S006    C002    50.00
```

and the table student is:

```
sno     sname   sage ssex
S003    BILL    25   M
S004    STEVE   20   F
S005    BAKR    20   F
S006    TOM     21   M
S007    JERRY   21   M
S008    MACY    21   F
S009    MICK    23   F
S010    COOKER  22   F
```

please can someone help me on this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you have to use mysql? It does not support minus, nor intersect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for `INNER JOIN` not `UNION`.

Does this give you the result you're after?

```
SELECT student.*, subjcode.cno, subjcode.score
FROM student
INNER JOIN subjcode ON subjcode.sno = student.sno
WHERE student.sno LIKE '%S001%';
```

Comment: sorry sir but it didn't work it is just blank but thanks :(

Comment: @jack The problem could also be that I used a lower case "s" in 's001'.  I just noticed yours was capitalized.  I edited the statement and changed the `WHERE` clause from = to `LIKE`, which ignores case

Comment: your first query sir worked i've just change the"=" to "!=" so thank you very much sir